# Android Version 11 force 3G, 4G Only Network Radioinfo Setting

Tags: networking, apk, android-contentresolver, android-settings, sketchware

Please solve this code for Android Version 11 force Network 3G, 4G.
I'm using this code but showing error.

```
try{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.phone.settings.RadioInfo");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Device not supported" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try{
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.settings.RadioInfo");
startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Device not supported" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}